# Create world map from svg in android

Tags: android, android-maps, world-map, androidsvg

I want to create a custom world map using SVG. I have country JSON from https://github.com/Fil/visionscarto-world-atlas . How can I do this with SVG in android?[image]

Comment: You could use a WebView and run the javascript from that repo in that. Or you could generate and save the SVG and use an SVG library to render it in your app.  Which part are you stuck on?